# Correct my MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table like

```
CREATE TABLE `survey` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `submitdate` datetime default NULL,
 `answer` varchar(5) collate utf8_unicode_ci default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=499 ;
```

now to get values like

```
    c                t         Clicks   
2012-10-29  2012-10-22       10
2012-11-04  2012-10-30       20
2012-11-11  2012-11-05       30
2012-11-19  2012-11-12       34
```

I am using this query

```
SELECT uq.timespan, COALESCE(tsq.TotalClicks, 0) as Clicks FROM (
SELECT DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -21
DAY ) ) c, DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -28
DAY ) ) l
union SELECT DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -15
DAY ) ) c, DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -20
DAY ) ) l
union SELECT DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -8
DAY ) ) c, DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -14
DAY ) ) l
union SELECT curdate() c,DATE( DATE_ADD( NOW( ) , INTERVAL -7
DAY ) ) l
)uq LEFT JOIN (
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
                AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN  c 'to' l
DAY ) )
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
                AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN c 'to' l
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK
        AND submitdate < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN c 'to' l
DAY ) )
    WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN c 'to' l
           END Weeksubmitdate, 
           count(id) TotalClicks
FROM survey
WHERE submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK
GROUP BY Weeksubmitdate
)tsq ON uq.timespan = tsq.Weeksubmitdate";
```

problem is with 16th line c to l.

I am getting the following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''to' l
>   DAY ) )
>       WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK
>                  ' at line 16

Answer (score 1):

CASE is supposed to evaluate to a scalar expression. That means its THEN clauses must evaluate to scalar expressions too. Now, what does this `c 'to' l` thing stand for? Is it a scalar expression? It doesn't seem one to me, however I may be unaware of some things in MySQL, so it's more important whether MySQL itself recognises that as a scalar expression. And apparently it doesn't.

There is another issue. You are trying to reference a derived table's columns inside another derived table. More specifically, you seem to be trying to reference the columns `c` and `l` of `uq` *inside* the `tsq` subselect, and that is illegal. If `uq` was a normal table, it would be fine, but since it is a *virtual* table, the query doesn't know about its existence at *that* point, i.e. at the time of parsing the `tsq` subquery.

Anyway, what you seem to be doing with your query could probably be rewritten more simply, like this, for instance:

```
SELECT
  MIN(submitdate) AS startdate,
  MAX(submitdate) AS enddate,
  COUNT(*) AS clicks
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 WEEK THEN 1
      WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK THEN 2
      WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 WEEK THEN 3
      WHEN submitdate >= NOW() - INTERVAL 4 WEEK THEN 4
    END AS weekid,
    *
  FROM survey
) s
GROUP BY
  weekid
ORDER BY
  startdate
;
```

The subquery assigns surrogate week IDs to every row of `survey`. The main query groups the results by those IDs and produces the counts as well as starting & ending dates for every group.